# How do podman containers make connections and port issues?

Tags: podman

Question 1: not root user cannot create a nginx application with a port number of 80?

> Podman can not create containers that bind to ports < 1024.
>
> Non priv users are not allowed to bind to ports < 1024, so this requires root.

So I can only create nginx under root?
And I also need PHP and mariadb to support my site, I've tried to reference PHP in nginx's configuration file:

```
location ~ \.php(.*)$ {
    fastcgi_pass   php:9000;
    ...
}
```

Check with `nginx -t` and report an error:
`nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "php" in ...`

But docker works that way

What should I do？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docker daemon, running with root privileges, manages networks on a system level. It creates extra networks, in which the docker containers have an ip address, and connects the host to these networks.

As far as I can tell, a rootless podman process creates those networks as well, but can't connect the host to these internal podman networks, as it doesn't have sufficient privileges.

But rootless podman can map the ports of containers to ports > 1024, because this doesn't require root privileges.

My workaround:

1. I expose the web application running in my rootless podman container to a high port like 8090.
2. I setup an NGINX reverse proxy to proxy_pass incoming traffic from port 443 to port 8090.
3. I configure ufw (any firewall will do) to block traffic to port 8090 from the outside.

This way, the web application can run in a rootless container and still be accessible on a standard port like 80 or 443. And with nginx as a reverse proxy, you can even manage Let's Encrypt certificates at a central point.

Note: in step 1, you have to specify a port mapping in your podman command. Something like `podman run -p 127.0.0.1:8090:80 image`.

And for completeness, my nginx config looks similar to this:

```
server {
        server_name example.org;
        
        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8090/;
                proxy_set_header    Host                $http_host;
                proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto   $scheme;

        }
}
```